# Wireless or wired LAN: Which consumes less power?

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, energy-saving

I have a printer that has Ethernet LAN and Wi-Fi WLAN. The printer is seldom used, so I'm interested in minimizing idle power consumption.

My Wi-Fi AP is on anyway, so that's not interesting.
My first guess would be that a wired LAN connection would use less power, because there's not so much power lost "in space". But on the other hand, I vaguely remember that at least gigabit Ethernet sends a constant signal or something, while Wi-Fi only sends something if there is something to send?

So how should I connect my printer to minimize idle power usage? If Ethernet, would it make any difference if I reconfigure the ethernet link to 100 Mbit/s or even 10 Mbit/s?

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: Is your printer actually gigabit ethernet, or just the router? If you can disable gigabit ethernet speeds, there wouldn't be any comparison with wifi power consumption.

Comment: @Thebluefish: I guess, it's 100 mbit only. I haven't checked yet, have to do that.

Comment: @joeqwerty: The question is either "How much power does each of the media consume?" or "Which to prefer to safe power?"

Comment: I changed the title to "Which consumes less Power", which is the second question "Which to prefer to save power?". You can open another question to find out how much power each consumes and how to find that out.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is still rather unclear. However, I assume you are you interested in whether you should use, from a power consumption point of view, your printer's wifi or the wired ethernet.

To be sure you should measure it with a power meter, but I think it won't make much of a difference, as I would be surprised if the printer is optimized towards this. Stating the make and model would also help.
Also, you should check if you can disable the wifi on your printer. If you can't then it's even more likely that it won't make a difference.

IMO, if you're interested in saving power (good!), just turn off the printer when you don't use it (which seems to be often as you say it's "only used seldom"). As a bonus: walking to and reaching out to turn on the printer is a good exercise as well.

Comment: Note that laser printers in particular can have quite high power requirements when being turned on, although that is likely to only last for a few seconds.